# How to send an email, via ExchangeService C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I have to send an email through Exchange. I found that I can do this using `ExchangeService`. I've tried many ways to do this, but only what I've got is error: (440) Login Timeout.

I don't even know if there is a problem with credentials, or my code is wrong.

```
string login = @"login";
string password = @"password";
ExchangeService service = new ExangeService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
service.Url = new Uri(@"https://mail.exchangemail.com");

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = "Interesting";
message.Body = "The proposition has been considered.";
message.ToRecipients.Add("quarkpol@gmail.com");
message.From = "quarkpol_test@gmail.com";
message.Send();
```

Comment: Did you try login into quarkpol@gmail.com online with the credentials you entered in code?

Comment: I assume that the miss-spelling of `ExangeService` isn't your issue.

Comment: Miss-spelling isn't the issue. What I've got from server admin is login and password. Login is not an email address. It's just a login(one word). I also have got server's address it's mail.exchangemail.com.

Comment: @quarkpol have you tried following the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

Comment: I think the problem is about your account permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problrm solution on the web, and it works.

```
using EASendMail;

string login = @"login";
string password = @"password";

SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

oMail.From = "from@email.com";
oMail.To = "to@email.com";
oMail.AddAttachment(fileName, fileByteArray);

oMail.Subject = "Subject";
oMail.HtmlBody = "HTMLBody";

SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("mail.email.com");

oServer.Protocol = ServerProtocol.ExchangeEWS;
oServer.User = login;
oServer.Password = password;

oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

try
{
    Console.WriteLine("start to send email ...");
    oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
    Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
}
catch (Exception ep)
{
    Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
    Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
}
```